# How to resolve the DNS issue on a linux guest

Tags: dns

I have a VM guest having this issue:

```
[rxie@pocnnr1n1 opt]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search 8.8.8.8
```

8.8.8.8 is pingable

google.com is not resolvable

```
[rxie@pocnnr1n1 opt]$ ping google.com 
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

How do I fix the issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: yes, I said 8.8.8.8 is pingable in my OP, thank you.

Comment: Is port 53 open?
`sudo tcpdump -i any -n -nn -s 0 -p port 53`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `search` option is for configuring default domain suffixes, not for configuring nameservers.

Use `nameserver 8.8.8.8` instead. If this comes from NetworkManager, carefully check whether you've entered the DNS server address in the wrong field. If this comes from DHCP... fix the DHCP server.

Comment: Thank you, that is the reason!